# pip install mysqlclient with Python 3.8 not working

Tags: python, mysql, django, pip

I have a django project with Python 3.8 and I am trying to install **mysqlclient** library through: `pip install mysqlclient` command. I got this error:

```
MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

1. I tried installation by using wheel file from where ( I tried every wheel from this [site](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient) ) but I got the error: `*...is not a supported wheel on this platform.*`
2. I tried to install it from the [source](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/) but when I run this command `python setup.py install` I got the same error:

```
  MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

3. I tried this command `pip install --only-binary :all: mysqlclient` and I got the error:

   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysqlclient (from versions: )
   No matching distribution found for mysqlclient

   Please let me know if you have some suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+install+mysqlclient

Comment: Let me explain these errors one by one. "*Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h'*" You need source code of `libmysqlclient`. "*not a supported wheel on this platform*" Either you downloaded a wheel for a different Python version or you have 32/64-bit problem (32-bit Python and 64-bit wheel; or 64-bit Python and 32-bit wheel); download the correct wheel that corresponds to your Python.

Comment: "*Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysqlclient (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for mysqlclient*" `mysqlclient` projects [provides wheels](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/1.4.6/#files) only for 64-bit Pythons. Probably you have 32-bit. Install 64-bit Python.

Answer (score 0):

> `Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory`

You are missing the `mysql` library that is needed as a requirement when compiling `mysqlclient` from source.

> is not a supported wheel on this platform

I bet you have a 32-bit python installed. All the whl files for `mysqlclient` on pypi are for amd64, which would explain why there is no supported version for your setup. You can check by:

1. Check your installation path, if it contains something like `python38-32`, then you have the 32 bit version for sure
2. Type `python` in the `cmd` and check the first line. For me (64 bit python), it contains the string `MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)`

What you can do about it is uninstall the 32 bit version and install the 64 bit one, after all `mysqlclient` will not be the last tool that does not have 32 bit whl files available on pypi OR you could download the 32 bit whl file for `mysqlclient` from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient)